# What is the third argument to property?

Tags: python

I am learning oriented object programming, but I can not understand why the last method `def del_age(self)` doesn't execute? According to my `age=property(get_age,set_age,del_age)`, `del_age` have been included in property. Why isn't it called?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__age=29

    def get_age(self):    
        print("get_age")
        return self.__age

    def set_age(self,value):   
        print("set_age")
        if value<0:
            value=0
        self.__age=value

    def del_age(self):     
        print("del_age")
        del self.__age

    age=property(get_age,set_age,del_age)  


p=Person()
p.age=19
print(p.age)
```

The output is like below.

```
set_age
get_age
19
```

Comment: Did you try `del p.age`?

Comment: Why dont you use @property - its easier to read.

Comment: *Why* do you think `del_age` should *ever be called here*?

Comment: @L3viathan well, `__del__` is irrelevant here.

Comment: There is no reason for *del_age* to be called

Comment: As an aside, stop using double-underscore name-mangling unecessarily: `__age` should just be `_age`

Comment: @BrutusForcus  Why there is no reason for del_age to be called?  Why the other two methods have been called? Can you provide detailed explanation, please?

Comment: @L3viathan  If del_age is not guaranteed to be called, why it is inside of the property()?

Comment: If you want to delete the property you would call *del p.age*. That would utilise your function

Comment: `p.age=19` calls `set_age`, `print(p.age)` calls `get_age`. If you want `del_age` to be called you can call `del p.age`

Comment: @XiangyuanLi In general, no function is guaranteed to be called.  They are either called or they are not.   Clearly del_age is not automatically called in this instance, but it works if the object reference is explicitly deleted.

Comment: @XiangyuanLi My comment was misleading. The deleter is called when you attempt to delete the attribute with `del`.

Comment: @PeterWood  If the age=property(get_age,set_age,del_age) doesn't mean I can call get_age, set_age, del_age together, what does it mean?

Comment: See my answer for an example of how to call deleter method. But I agree, that it goes without saying that if you don't call it, the attribute won't be deleted.

Comment: @L3viathan  If so, what does  age=property(get_age,set_age,del_age)  mean?

Comment: @XiangyuanLi you're saying that `age` is a `property` and these are the functions to use to get/set/delete it, and they will be mapped to `.`, `=`, and `del`.

Comment: @PeterWood  If so, why del_age can not be called ?  I need detailed explanation or reason, please.

Comment: @XiangyuanLi you need a detailed explanation of why you think `del_age` can't be called. `p.del_age()` and `del p.age` both work, the second being a shortcut for the first.

Answer (score 3):

Your `del_age`, the third argument to `property(get_age,set_age,del_age)`, is the deleter. It specifies what happens if you execute

```
del p.age
```

on your instance `p`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score -1):

Use the `@property` decorator instead - I feel it's much more Pythonic in general.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 29

    @property
    def age(self):
        print("get_age")
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        print("set_age")
        if value < 0:
            value = 0
        self._age = value

    @age.deleter
    def age(self):
        print("del_age")
        del self._age


p = Person()
p.age = 19
print(p.age)

# call the deleter method
del p.age

try:
    print(p.age)
except AttributeError:
    print('delete is successful')
else:
    print('Error! expected deleter to be called')
```

Output:

```
set_age
get_age
19
del_age
get_age
delete is successful
```

Links for reference

- [Python @property decorator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't answer the OP's question at all, which may be a bit unclear. But it doesn't even address it.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Great! Yes, it can be a bit annoying getting downvotes without explanations, but not everyone have time or energy to give criticism (and follow up on responses), and those who do lose their anonymity and becomes open for abuse. So it's a bit of a necessity.